# Unable to toggleClass to change the main image in a gallery when a thumbnail is clicked

Tags: jquery, image, toggleclass

I am attempting to produce a simple image gallery.

Currently I have one large class with a background image containing a full size version of one of the lower 5 thumbnails. When I click on one of the 5 thumbnails I want the background image of the large class to change to a larger version of the thumbnail that was just clicked.

I have attempted to use the `toggleClass()` method to change the class to one with a background image that matches the thumbnail image but currently it isn't working.

I set up a [**JSfiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/k5REw/) to demonstrate with the first two thumbnails, currently changing the class should only change the background color to simplify it a bit.

So why isn't the class being changed when the second image with id `thumb2` is clicked?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sytnax issue:-

Change this

```
$(".main-image1").toggleClass(".main-image2");
```

to

```
$(".main-image1").toggleClass("main-image2");
```

When providing a class selector you need to provide `.` but in the add/remove/toggleClass operation it should be the name of the class alone.

#### [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sMFb9/)

Answer (score 3):

Remove the dot in `main-image2`

```
$(".main-image1").toggleClass("main-image2");
```

Answer (score 1):

use

```
$(".main-image1").toggleClass("main-image2");
```

Don't use `.` at the `toggleClass()`

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/k5REw/1/)